# Making a command with multiple arguments in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am fairly new at coding with javascript and I wanted to make a discord bot through it, but I am having difficulties when it comes to commands with multiple arguments.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ + /g);
    const command = args[0].slice(Prefix.length).toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'test') {
        if (!args[1]) return message.reply('no argument');
        if (args[2]) return message.reply('Too many arguments');
        switch(args[1]){
            case 'one':
                message.reply('test one');
                break;
            case 'two':
                message.reply('test two');
                break;
        };
    }
});
```

It will pick up if there is no argument but if an argument is send with the command it won't send a message or an error, so I do not know what I am doing wrong. Could someone help me understand arguments a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

       switch (args[0]) {
           case 'test':
                if(!args[1]) return message.reply('no argument');
                 if(args[2]) return message.reply('Too many arguments')

            if (args[1] === 'one') {
                message.channel.send('test one');
            } else  if (args[1] === 'two') {
                message.channel.send('test two');
            } else 
                message.channel.send('Invalid arguments')
            }
            break;

}})
```

Maybe like this

Answer (score 0):

`/ + /` matches one or more spaces, followed by a space, meaning it only splits on two spaces. Split on `/\s+/` for one or more spaces instead:

```js
const args = message.content.trim().split(/\s+/g);
```